# Compare big gapped data columns in chart

Tags: charts, libreoffice-calc, data-comparison

I have these related columns:

```
col1 data range 1500 - 3000
col2 data range 27 - 50
col3 data range 0 - 30
```

I want to show the relation between those columns in a chart. But as col1 is so far apart from the other I just see the line of col1 and the other two are barely more than a straight line at the bottom of the chart.

How can I drag them up so the values are correct but I can still see the correlation between all columns?
What I would actually need are three charts that overlay each other.

I did not find any option for this in LibreOffice Calc 3.5.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to handle differently-scaled data when creating a chart. The easiest way is to "scale" the raw data; e.g., to divide every value in col1 by 1000 and use the result as source data for the chart.

If modifying the source data is no option, you could use different scales for col1 on the one hand, col2/3 on the other. Starting with the following dummy data:

[image]

If you've selected the data series for column `C`, you could align the chart columns to the secondary Y axis, while columns `A`/`B` keep aligned to the primary Y axis.

[image]

LO will adapt the scale of the secondary Y axis automatically by default:

[image]

Another option would be combining a default primary Y axis with a logarithmic-scaled secondary X axis...

[image]

... resulting in:

[image]

But generally, i would refrain from combining a "normal" primary X axis with a logarithmic secondary Y scale, since such a chart will be very hard to interpret.

In any case, i would recommend to **enable data labels** to display the values together with the columns.

*PS: All charts created with LO 4.2.3.3*